# Scrapy CrawlSpider Rule 'Allow' is resulting in a "Documentation not found" error

Tags: python, scrapy

i'm trying to scrape data off all the fights in UFC stats such as this page [UFCStats](http://ufcstats.com/fight-details/78afed76d0e9a639)

However, when using  'allow' and 'callback', pycharm is throwing me a "Documentation not found" error. Screenshot here [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiwIW.png).

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

# http://ufcstats.com/statistics/events/completed
# http://ufcstats.com/event-details/335ad945324c3a2e
# http://ufcstats.com/fight-details/e786542667fdecf0
      
class UFCSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = 'UFC'
        allowed_domains = ['ufcstats.com']
        start_urls = [
            'http://ufcstats.com/'
        ]
        rules = [
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='fight-details'), callback= 'parse_item')
        ]
```

Could anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Try run the spider directly on the terminal/ command line and see if you get the same error. Might be an error related to pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Define the rules as below. *callback* is an argument of Rule class, not LinkExtractor.

```
 rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('fight-details', )), callback='parse_item'),
    ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately i'm still getting the same "Documentation not found" error. Any other ideas?